# SharePoint 2013 ListViewByQuery control does not show ribbon

Tags: 2013, document-library, ribbon, view, list-view-web-part

I put in my aspx page a ListViewByQuery control, to show a view on a library, based on a query that is dynamically constructed.

But, when I click on an item in the control, it does not show the document & library ribbon tabs. I already tried several things but none of them work.
This is the last thing i tried:

aspx page:

```
<SharePoint:ListViewByQuery ID="lvqDossierFiles" runat="server" />
```

code behind:

```
SPRibbon current = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this);
if (current != null)
{
     current.CommandUIVisible = true;
     current.MakeTabAvailable(SPRibbon.ReadTabId);
     current.MakeTabAvailable(SPRibbon.DocumentTabId);
     current.MakeTabAvailable(SPRibbon.LibraryTabId);
     current.CheckForInitializationReadiness = false;
     current.InitialTabId = SPRibbon.ReadTabId;
     current.Minimized = false;
}
```

Someone has an idea?